# Oracle global_names DELETE problem

Tags: sql, oracle, distributed-transactions, delete-row

I'm using a database link to execute a DELETE statement on another DB, but the DB link name doesn't conform to global naming, and this requirement cannot change.
Also I have global_names set to false, and cannot be changed either.

When I try to use these links however, I receive:

```
ORA-02069: - global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operation

Cause: A remote mapping of the statement is required but cannot be achieved because   
GLOBAL_NAMES should be set to TRUE for it to be achieved. -

Action: Issue `ALTER SESSION SET GLOBAL_NAMES = TRUE`   (if possible)
```

What is the alternative action when setting `global_names=true` is not possible?

Cheers,
Jean

Answer (score 1):

That parameter can be set at the session level.  Could you not set the GLOBAL_NAMES value equal to TRUE in your session, execute your delete, then set if back to FALSE?  If not could you create a new connections just for this delete and update the GLOBAL_NAMES value in that session to be true?

Comment: You mean create a new connection so that I could alter session? Well let's say that ALTER SESSION is not acceptable here... thank you

Comment: @jyzuz:  Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `GLOBAL_NAMES` parameter is set to TRUE in your environment. That requires that the DB link have the *same name* as the `GLOBAL_NAME` of the remote DB.

[Here's a link which describes the situation more fully.](http://www.dbmotive.com/support/oracle-error-codes/?type=ORA&errcode=02085)

Comment: in my environment GLOBAL_NAMES is set to false. And even if I alter session and set to TRUE this will not solve my problem, since the DB_LINK has diffent name then the remote database, and I cannot change this requirement. Thanks.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that you can't change the link name, nor the naming conventions used by the databases involved. Sounds like you're in an impossible spot then.